# pivot table in laravel 4 insertion

Tags: laravel-4, pivot, eloquent

hey guys im new in laravel and i was trying to insert into my pivot table. i have this structure in my database

[image]

the departments table belongs to many categories and same as category so i have this models

```
 use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

 class Departments extends Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'departments';

protected $fillable = ['department_name'];

public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 public function categories()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Categories');
  }
  }


   use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
   use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

   class Categories extends Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'categories';

protected $fillable = ['name'];

public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */

public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Departments');
}

 }
```

then i have a query in my controller like this

```
  $messages = array(
        'required' => 'Please Fill the required field',
        'unique'    => 'Name Already exist'
    );

    $catName = Input::get('categoryName');
    $deptId = Input::get('deptId');

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(),[
        'categoryName' => 'required|unique:categories,name' ], $messages);

     if($validation->fails()){ 
        return array('error' =>$validation->messages()->all() );
    }else{

        $findDepartment = Departments::find($deptId);

        $saveCat = $findDepartment->categories()->insert(array('name' => $catName));

}
```

but then when i checked the tables it adds up on the categories table but nothing is added in the category_department. do i miss any codes? and also i had an error last time I was trying to migrate my pivot table the error was this.

[image]

can you help me guys on what i am missing? tnx for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should name your model classes as singular: Category, Department.

Then try to declare your relationships with the pivot table name:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'category_department');
}
```

and

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Departments', 'category_department');
}
```

now, to insert new data, try attach:

```
$findDepartment = Department::find($deptId);

$category = Category::where('name', '=', $catName)->first();

$saveCat = $findDepartment->categories()->attach($category->id);
```

Comment: what if i would like to insert a multiple department with the same category? how will i do that in a single query?

Comment: then you could use sync $findDepartment->categories()->sync(array(1, 2, 3));

Comment: hmmm.. i was trying to have an multiple departments on 1 user this is what i did http://pastie.org/8969588 but then im having this error :Illegal offset type

Comment: sorry i don'd understand the question

Comment: i mean the values of the data in sync array are unique